# ¿Las comillas son importantes en las consultas a mysql?

Tags: mysql

Concretamente me refiero a estas -> ``` `` ``` a la hora de seleccionar los campos a consultar.

Entiendo que a la hora de meter `values` si es importante para decirle si es un número o un string, pero para seleccionar los campos funciona tanto si las pones como si no.

Es por esto que no tengo muy claro si son importantes o no.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Primeramente es importante distinguir entre estos dos tipos de comillas:

- `` ` ` ``: que son llamadas en MySQL comillas de identificación (en inglés se llaman *backticks*)
- `' '` : estas son las comillas simples de toda la vida.

### ▸ Las comillas de identificación `` ` ` ``

Sólo son obligatorias cuando en la consulta estás usando un nombre de tabla o columna que es **[una palabra reservada de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-in-current-series)**. En ese caso, si no las usas, la consulta sería errónea porque confundirá tu tabla o columna con esa palabra reservada.

Por ejemplo, si en una tabla tienes una columna llamada `sum`, dado que `SUM` es una palabra reservada de MySQL, esta consulta sería errónea:

```
SELECT sum FROM tu_tabla;
```

Para evitar el error, tendrás que rodear la columna por comillas de identificación:

```
SELECT `sum` FROM tu_tabla;
```

Así la consulta funcionará.

**Nota:** Recomendaría no usar palabras reservadas en nombres de tablas o de columnas.

---

### ▸ Las comillas simples `' '`

Son las que se usan para indicar que se trata de una cadena y no de un valor numérico o booleano. **No son lo mismo que las comillas de identificación**.

Esta consulta funcionará sin problemas:

```
SELECT `sum` FROM tu_tabla WHERE nombre='Pedro';
```

Pero si tú usas comillas de identificación para `Pedro` el manejador interpretará que `Pedro` es una columna. De modo que al ejecutar esta consulta:

```
SELECT `sum` FROM tu_tabla WHERE nombre=`Pedro`;
```

Te arrojará el error siguiente:

> Unknown column 'Pedro' in 'where clause'

Comment: Genial, muchísimas gracias por la explicación :) ya lo tengo claro. Como no suelo usar palabras reservadas por eso no me falla XD