# Consulta Mysql desde URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, get

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es una consulta a MySQL con PHP y que traiga los resultados de la fila especificada en la URL.
Por ejemplo mi URL es esta: https://searya.com/ref/?nick=Gabi3811
Entonces que la consulta traiga los resultados de la fila que contenga ese nick (el nick es único, es como un ID).

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es esta consulta con PHP pero algo estoy haciendo mal, no conozco bien las funciones y tampoco sé de qué forma buscarlo en google.

conexion.php:

```
<?php
$host_name = '***';
$database = 'searya';
$user_name = 'plugins';
$password = '***';
$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
} else {
    if(isset($_GET['nick'])){
        $nick=$_GET['nick']; 
        $query = "SELECT * FROM referralsystem3 WHERE name = '$nick'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    }else{
        echo "No se pasaron datos en el GET";}
}
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
    include("php/conexion.php");
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
    <h1 class="***"><?php echo $fila['nick'] ?> Te ha invitado</h1>
<?php
    }
?>
```

El error que recibo en la página es:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: name in X:\...\conexion.php on line 13
```

Como se habrán dado cuenta hasta me cuesta explicarlo ya que no se muy bien qué herramientas se utilizan para hacer esto, y leí en un foro que es con $_GET.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Ten cuidado, y mucho más si es desde una web. Pasando la consulta así te pueden inyectar código malicioso. Pueden, desde borrar/alterar tus datos en la base de datos, hasta colarse en tu sistema. Se recomienda el uso de consultas preparadas, para protegerte contra ese grave peligro de seguridad.

Comment: gracias por avisar, voy a hacer funcionar lo que quiero y luego voy a agregarle la seguridad.

Comment: Entendido. En cuanto al error, mejor usa variables, y verifica lo que hay en el `GET`. Algo así: **`if(isset($_GET['nick'])){$nick=$_GET['nick']; $query = "SELECT * FROM referralsystem3 WHERE name = '$nick'"; //CUIDADO con la Inyección SQL... resto del código  }else{echo "No se pasaron datos en el GET";}`**. Verás que he puesto la variable en la SQL rodeada de comillas simples, `' '`,  se deben usar para los valores que no sean numéricos.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, agregue lo que me propusiste y avance un poco, ahora la página carga solo que no carga la variable, ahi actualice el tema para que veas como quedó. Tampoco estoy muy seguro de cómo hacerlo en el index. Nuevamente muchas gracias!

Comment: Es extraño, al parecer la columna `name` que usas en `$query` te está dando problemas. ¿Usas algún Framework que te restrinja el uso de ciertas palabras reservadas o algo así? Prueba a poner la consulta así: **$query = "SELECT * FROM referralsystem3 WHERE `name` = '$nick'";** O sea, pon `name` entre dos comillas de estas:  ``

Comment: En efecto, `name` es **una palabra reservada de MySQL**. Yo no la usaría nunca para un nombre de columna de una tabla. Aunque puedes usarlas, pero debes encerrarlas entre comillas de identificación, o esa, entre dos comillas de estas `` . **[Ver aquí palabras reservadas de MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-N)**. Hace poco tratamos precisamente ese tema en una pregunta:  [¿Las comillas son importantes en las consultas a mysql?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129545/29967) +

Comment: Que yo sepa no uso ningun tipo de frameworks como ese, lo unico que utilizo es Materialize. Las BD ya están creadas y son utilizadas por otro programa, tengo un server de un juego y uno de los plugins crea esa tabla, y yo necesito extraer de esa misma tabla algunos valores para hacer un sistema. Agregue `` a `name`y sigue igual. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes la consulta ahora? ¿Sigue dando el mismo error?

Comment: Perdon, ya lo resolví, había escrito mal '$nick' y puse '$name' cuando la variable anterior era $nick, ya me funciono perfecto, 1000 GRACIAS!! Ahora me voy a fijar el tema de la seguridad, posiblemente haga otro tema para consultar esos temas. Nuevamente muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a indicar en esta respuesta los puntos esenciales que hemos ido comentando hasta llegar a una solución del problema:

- Verificar con [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) si el dato fue pasado en el `GET` y almacenarlo en una variable. Así escribimos un código más claro
- Dado que en la base de datos tienes una columna llamada `name`, que es una [**palabra reservada** de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-N), **es obligatorio** encerrar esa columna entre dos comillas de identificación `` en la consulta.
- Más adelante (no muy tarde), **considera darle seguridad a tu código, protegiéndolo contra la [Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)**.

Tomando en cuenta este último punto, para fines de resolución del problema actual, el código puede quedar así:

**Código:**

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>');
} else {
    if(isset($_GET['nick'])){
        $nick=$_GET['nick']; 

        /*Cuidado aquí con la Inyección de código. Usa consultas preparadas*/
        $query = "SELECT * FROM referralsystem3 WHERE `name` = '$nick'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    }else{
        echo "No se pasaron datos en el GET";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, las variables que se envían por url se obtienes con la variable `$_GET`, pero aquí hay un error, la url es https://searya.com/ref/?nick=Gabi3811. La variable que pasas se llama `nick`(y su valor es Gabi3811, nick=Gabi3811) y tú tratas de accesar a ella por medio de `name` lo cual es incorrecto.

La consulta correcta sería así:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM referralsystem3 WHERE name = $_GET['nick']";
```

y en el resultado que te devuelve se accesa así:

```
<h1 class="header center teal-text text-lighten-2">
   <?php echo $fila['nick'] ?> Te ha invitado
</h1>
```

Puedes leer más acerca del uso de la vaible $_GET [aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php).

Nota: Este código es para un ejemplo didáctico, obviamente hace falta validar la variable que recibimos para evitar una [inyección de código](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, de todos modos fue un error mio de tipeo en el mensaje, en realidad está todo con "name", lo cambie a nick en el ejemplo ya que con name se podía entender que los nombres se repiten, por lo tanto las respuestas a la consulta se pueden extraer de varias filas y no un resultado preciso. Ahi edite el tema para que no haya confusiones.