# Replace Mysql no trabaja

Tags: mysql, sql

Cuando trato de realizar un replace a todos los registros de un campo, me indica un error de sintaxis el cual no entiendo, este el el query.

```
 UPDATE tabla 
 SET campo=REPLACE(campo,'\.','');
```

Y me salen dos alertas

1 - Se encontró una nueva declaración pero no hay delimitador entre este y el anterior. (cerca del replace)

2 - símbolo token inesperado cerca de '.'

Comment: ¿Qué quiers reemplazar? \., . o \

Comment: ¿Tu nombre de tabla o algún nombre de columna son **[palabras reservadas de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-A)**? Si es así, debes ponerlos entre comillas de identificación... lo que quiero decir es que pruebes poniendo `tabla` y `campo` (las dos veces), entre comillas de identificación de MySQL... No me refiero a las comillas simples `'`, sino a las de identificación... [Ver aquí ya que en comentarios no salen esas comillas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129545/29967). También revisa que tu  versión de mysql está actualizada.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar lo que quieres remplazar en un where

`UPDATE tabla 
 SET campo=REPLACE(campo,'\.','') WHERE campo like '%\.%';`