# Contar campos mysqli

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

****tengo una tabla llamada lugares y el campo que quiero contar se llama estado los valores que puede tener estados es 0 = tramitado , 1= aceptado, 2=rechazado
quiero que los imprima asi ya lo hice count pero me aprece renglon por renglon y don sum if apareceria como la imagen pero no entiendo como  ****

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el query que intente pero los suma no los cuenta

```
SELECT sum(IF(estado=0,1,2)) as "tramite", sum(IF(estado=1,2,0)) 
as "Aceptado", sum(IF(estado=2,0,1)) as "Rechazado" FROM lugares
```

Comment: Agrega la estructura de la tabla

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor explica mejor lo que quieres, muestra la estructura de la tabla y la consulta que has intentado. [Puedes editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/205297/edit) para mejorarla. Gracias.

Comment: y la estrctura de la tabla?

Comment: no se que opines @A.Cedano pero me parece que con `sum(case....) ` se pudiera resolver esto o no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un `SUM(CASE ... WHEN)`,  por ejemplo:

```
SELECT
       SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Tramite,
       SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Aceptado,
       SUM(CASE WHEN estado = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Rechazado       
FROM lugares;
```

Lo que hará será sumar `1` cuando cada condición se cumpla.

Comment: solo una duda se puede omitir la palabra `AS` para colocarle un alias a cada columna resultante?

Comment: @shadow sí claro. Por cierto, podría ser una pregunta interesante. Yo siempre lo uso así, pero nunca he investigado a qué se debe que se pueda usar u omitir  `AS`. Yo lo omito porque el código queda más elegante :)

Comment: de hecho si es algo curioso, por que por ejemplo yo siempre lo hago así `AS 'Trámite'` es decir el alias lo coloco entre comillas; jamás me habia detenido a pensar en que pasaría si lo declaro de otro modo; investigaré

Comment: @shadow, [lee por ejemplo esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129545/29967). Si vas a usar como nombre de columna una palabra reservada (lo cual no recomendaría), entonces deberías usar comillas de identificación para nombrar esa columna (al menos en MySQL).