# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente error y luego de revisar en foros y demás no he dado con el motivo ¿podrían darme una mano? estoy incursionando en esto del php + html y la verdad es que no he encontrado la falla:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

**PHP:**

```
<?php
#Conexión
include('config.php');

#Captura Variables
$Dni = isset($_POST["Dni"])?$_POST["Dni"]:'';
$Name = isset($_POST["Name"])?$_POST["Name"]:'';
$LastName = isset($_POST["LastName"])?$POST["LastName"]:'';
$Phone = isset($_POST["Phone"])?$POST["Phone"]:'';
$CommentDate = isset($_POST["CommentDate"])?$_POST["CommentDate"]:'';
$CommentHour = isset($_POST["CommentHour"])?$_POST["CommentHour"]:'';
$Diagnosis = isset($_POST["Diagnosis"])?$_POST["Diagnosis"]:'';
$Accept = isset($_POST["Accept"])?$_POST["Accept"]:'';
$Eps = isset($_POST["Eps"])?$_POST["Eps"]:'';
$Range = isset($_POST["Range"])?$_POST["Range"]:'';
$StatusEps = isset($_POST["StatusEps"])?$_POST["StatusEps"]:'';
$SentBy = isset($_POST["SentBy"])?$_POST["SentBy"]:'';
$Ips = isset($_POST["Ips"])?$_POST["Ips"]:'';
$AppointmentDate = isset($_POST["AppointmentDate"])?$_POST["AppointmentDate"]:'';
$AppointmentHour = isset($_POST["AppointmentHour"])?$_POST["AppointmentHour"]:'';
$CallsNumber = isset($_POST["CallsNumber"])?$_POST["CallsNumber"]:'';
$Comment = isset($_POST["Comment"])?$_POST["Comment"]:'';
$TimeStamp = strtotime("now");

#Insert
$Sql = "INSERT INTO BitPriorities ('PK_UUID','FK_Patient','FK_EPS','FK_Range','FK_Ips','FK_Diagnosis','Dni','Name0','LastName0','SentBy','Comment0','CommentDate','AppointmentDate','Accept','StatusEps','AppointmentHour','CommentHour','CallsNumber','imageb64','z_xOne','created','updated','createdUser','updatedUser') VALUES ('1', $Dni, $Eps, $Range, $Ips, $Diagnosis, $Dni,$Name,$LastName, $SentBy,$Comment,$CommentDate,$AppointmentDate,$Accept,$StatusEps,$AppointmentHour,$CommentHour,$CallsNumber,'1',1,$TimeStamp ,'','Julian','')"; 

if(mysqli_query($conn, $Sql)){
       echo "Records added successfully.";
   } else{
       echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Diria que los values de tu consulta INSERT deben ir entrecomillados. Es decir, en lugar de así:  `VALUES ('1', $Dni, $Eps,` que sea así: `VALUES ('1', '$Dni', '$Eps',` etc

Comment: Aparte de lo que te señala @masterguru, otro problema en tu consulta es que usas comillas simples para los nombres de columna, cuando deberías usar comillas de identificación, conocidas en inglés como *backticks*. Para más detalles sobre esto, puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129545/29967).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincido con los comentarios en que (Creo) deberian ir así:

```
$Sql = "INSERT INTO BitPriorities ('PK_UUID','FK_Patient','FK_EPS','FK_Range','FK_Ips','FK_Diagnosis','Dni','Name0','LastName0','SentBy','Comment0','CommentDate','AppointmentDate','Accept','StatusEps','AppointmentHour','CommentHour','CallsNumber','imageb64','z_xOne','created','updated','createdUser','updatedUser') VALUES ('1', '$Dni', '$Eps', '$Range', '$Ips', '$Diagnosis', '$Dni','$Name','$LastName', '$SentBy','$Comment','$CommentDate','$AppointmentDate','$Accept','$StatusEps','$AppointmentHour','$CommentHour','$CallsNumber','1',1,'$TimeStamp' ,'','Julian','')";
```

Lo que he hecho es poner las variables que declaras entre '', de forma que la estructura quedaría así:

$Sql = INSERT INTO BitPriorities ('Campo1','Campo2') VALUES ('$campo1','$campo2')

Comment: Como los comentarios son efímeros, pulsa en [edit] y explica qué cambios has hecho. Lee [answer].